# Abstract property in class cannot be accessed in the constructor

Tags: typescript, abstract-class

In the following example, I'm getting the TypeScript error `Abstract property 'name' in class 'Minigame' cannot be accessed in the constructor.`

I'm struggling to think how I could implement this. I can't pass the concrete class' name into the `super()` call because I can't access properties of the object before that call, and I can't make the properties `static` because the abstract class can't enforce that.

How should this be organized to guarantee every `Minigame` instantiates an `Explanation` object, which requires the concrete class' name property? Is making the name `static` (and removing the abstract requirement) really my best option to keep it simple?

```
abstract class Minigame {
    abstract name: string;
    explanation: Explanation;

    constructor() {
        this.explanation = new Explanation(this.name);
    }
}

class SomeGame extends Minigame {
    name = "Some Game's Name";

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't make sense because `name = 'Some Game's Name'` will be initialized after the `super()` call in the transpiled code, so when `this.explanation = new Explanation(this.name);` is executed, `this.name` will not yet be initialized.

Comment: Ah, I guess that's the same problem I mentioned as not being able to use the class properties before the `super()` call. Not really different _during_ the `super()` call either. Hmm. I just wonder if there's a graceful way to do this other than instantiating required things outside of the constructor?

Comment: I just had the awkward moment where I found this question on Google when looking up this issue again, I think I understand this general question and answer about the concept better now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63758747/why-cant-i-access-an-abstract-property-in-the-constructor-of-a-typescript-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here another solution based on Tom Coton which does not forces to implement the `getName` method.

Just moving the `name` in abstract class as constructor argument.

```js
class Explanation {
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

abstract class Minigame {
    explanation: Explanation;  
    name: string;
    constructor(name) { 
        this.name = name;
        this.explanation = new Explanation(this.name);
    }
} 

class SomeGame extends Minigame {
    constructor() {
       super('some game')
    }

}

const game = new SomeGame();

console.log({ game: game })
```

you can check here by clicking in "Run"

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeAHcA7MAXAlgexdA3gLABQ0Z0aAtgKYBc0E6ATpigOYDcJ50wujTAK7B02JgAoqdBs1ZsAlAW49y6ABaYIAOinQAvBTA0upcgF8SF4iTAAjAWBG9wUaAFlWmNkepLTZaiRUDBwUegRkMDQsXA5yZTIpegE5Ex4+FAFhUQkkmRZ2RXxoBJV1TR0ffUNjUp5y7UDI6NDqlGoAdzggqJDccQbKmnk080sS62JQSBgAZWwaAHEqwPRqFAATGA8ULyri0oyskTFxIrryCEFEagkAcggF328aO-lSqysSI-RoF98DO0uvMlj4ziZvvxsCBqFoQNg2OJiv96P9oGZ5EA

In case of needing to re-create the `Explanation` every time the `name` is set you could use setter & getters in addition:

```js
class Explanation {
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

abstract class Minigame {
    explanation?: Explanation;   
    private _name?: string;

    set name(name: string | undefined) {
        this._name = name;
        if(name) {
         this.explanation =  new Explanation(name);
        }
    }

    get name(): string | undefined{
        return this._name;
    }

    constructor(name?: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
} 

class SomeGame extends Minigame { 

    constructor() {
        super('some game');
    }

}

const game = new SomeGame();

console.log({ game: game })
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeAHcA7MAXAlgexdA3gLABQ0Z0aAtgKYBc0E6ATpigOYDcJ50wujTAK7B02JgAoqdBs1ZsAlAW49y6ABaYIAOinQAvBTA0upcgF8SF4iTAAjAWBG9wUaAFlWmNkepLTZaiRUDBwUAH56BGQwNCxcDnJlMkQWADcMXwB9KQiZFnYTJIZqdEMaSR96ATloAB9oQRQAE2oAM1ZqJsUifxV1TS1sn30y6hMVckxWippuor6NbUDo2NCRimoAdzggmJDcGep5cYnoKx4rIrYS0fF5Ktl2Oobmto6mntPoJhLBJjx+tohsYipdenwUAJhKIJDkHvkFH4voCdMMDFITmQrGZoCQSKBIDAAMrYGgAcWGgXQ1GaMA8KC8w3wuOs4P4zGhYjuSNOEEEiGoEgA5BBSb5vDQhcdQXjiGCIYxoBLfOittASeSfHdCsQFdgQNQtCBsGxxMzlfRlWd5EA

Answer (score 9):

It's a little ugly for a string, but you could do:

```
abstract class Minigame {
    abstract GetName(): string;
    explanation: Explanation;

    constructor() {
        this.explanation = new Explanation(this.GetName());
    }
}

class SomeGame extends Minigame {
    GetName(): string {
        return "Some Game's Name";
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: nice it help me a lot. Just an small improvement, we can use a getter instead:
`get name(): string {`
`return 'Some Game's Name'`
`}`

Comment: @AngelFragaParodi i tried that but it did not work. are you sure about this?